# Initializing one structure with contents of another structure

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Let's say I have a structure type:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b[3];
    int c;
} __attribute__((packed)) foo_t;
```

And I initialize thusly:

```
foo_t first = { 1, { 2, 3, 4 }, 5 };
```

Now I want to create a second structure that is a subset of the first:

```
typedef struct
{
    int b[3];
    int c;
} __attribute__((packed)) bar_t;

bar_t second = { first.b[3], first.c }; //this should define first.c as 5
memcpy(second.b, first.b, 3 * sizeof(int));
```

If I print the values of each variable in `second`, the array `b` is defined correctly but `c` is just 0.

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", second.b[0], second.b[1], second.b[2], second.c);
```

outputs

```
2 3 4 0
```

Why doesn't `second.c` get populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question literally seconds after posting this.

In order to initialize the contents of a new structure with an array, you must put curly brackets around the array portion. Also, specifying `first.b[3]` as an initialization value will actually grab the 4th element of a 3-element array, which is undefined and bad code. `{0}` can be used as a placeholder for any arbitrarily sized array until memcpy is used on the next line. So the correct code segment should look like:

```
typedef struct
{
    int b[3];
    int c;
}__attribute__((packed)) bar_t;

bar_t second = { {0}, first.c}; //this should define first.c as 5
memcpy(second.b,first.b,3*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: ..which still leaves the question of what value `first.b[3]` is as `b` only has three elements and you copy the fourth element. Note that an initializer is a value, not a definition.

Comment: Huh, good point. I see what you're saying. What could I replace `first.b[3]` with in this context to act as a "place holder" until I do the memcpy on the next line? Note that in the real code I'm working on, the array is large, so explicitly typing `{first.b[0], first.b[1], first.b[2], first.b[3], first.b[4].... etc}` would be untenable.

Comment: I believe that in an initializer, all elements not specifically mentioned are set to zero, so `{{0},first.c}` should do the trick. Please test it.

Comment: Thumbs up, that works. I'll edit my answer. Thank you Paul.

Comment: But if "avoiding unnecessary instructions" would be a goal, then don't initialize it. Just do the memcpy and then do `second.c= first.c`. (Assuming automatic vaiables.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal, not sure I follow. The two structures do not have the same variables. `bar_t` is missing one of the variables that `foo_t` has. How would the `=` operator handle that?

Comment: @DanLaks: Nevermind: I read the code wrong. Friday morning eyes. You'd need to use a common substructure to do that. Which might actually be a better solution than a memcpy(), if one were to consider the long-term maintenance. (Especially, if one but not both of the two structures were modified. Using a common substructure, or embedding one into the other, would keep them in sync. Using memcpy(), there is no compile time check that the copy makes any sense.)

Comment: Please note that if not for the non-standard packed attribute, this code would be completely unsafe, since `foo_t` and `bar_t` are not guaranteed to have the same padding layout. Good program design would have been to make `foo_t` contain a `bar_t`. Then you could simply do `foo_t foo = ...; bar_t bar = foo.bar;`

Answer (score 0):

With respect to code maintenance, using `memcpy()` to copy parts of a structure to another of a different type, is problematic: what happens if one (but not both) of the structure types involved are modified?

Therefore, I'd suggest using

```
typedef struct
{
    int b[3];
    int c;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__)) bar;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    bar bar;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__)) foo;
```

Then, having

```
foo  first = {1, {2, 3, 4}, 5};
bar  second;
```

you can obviously do

```
second = foo.bar;
```

Personally, I'd suggest adding accessor macros, too:

```
#define BAR_B(var, index) ((var).b[index])
#define BAR_C(var)        ((var).c)

#define FOO_A(var)        ((var).a)
#define FOO_B(var, index) ((var).bar.b[index])
#define FOO_C(var)        ((var).bar.c)
```

which can be used as both lvalues and rvalues (i.e. either side in assignments). It makes maintenance easier, in case you need to re-split or rearrange the structure contents later; you don't then need to change the code itself, only modify the accessor macros.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition, `first.c` is parsed as the initializer for the second entry of `second.b`, which is immediately overwritten by `memcpy`. Incidentally, `first.b[3]` is an invalid access beyond the end of `first.b`.

In order for `second.c` to be initialized with the value of `first.c`, the initializer should be rewritten as:

```
bar_t second = { { 0 } , first.c};
memcpy(second.b, first.b, sizeof(second.b));
```

You can also get rid of the `memcpy` by initializing `second.b` elements explicitly:

```
bar_t second = { { first.b[0], first.b[1], first.b[2] }, first.c};
```

Also note that `__attribute__((packed))` is non portable and useless in your declarations as all types are identical. Avoid this kind of thing unless it is absolutely necessary.